# Looping through xml file images with 'simplexml' php

Tags: php, xpath, foreach, element, simplexml

Googled for hours and no joy.

iam using simple xml and doing all sorts of queries on my xml file. I can display an image ( 1 image) 
fine.

I cant get the foreach loop to display all the images. Well i can but i used [i++] and it displayed all the images but wouldnt stop looping!

Below displays 2 images. The first is to show basic display of 1 image and my understanding. 
The 2nd image is where i want all the looping to happen.

```
$reference  = $_POST['varname'];
$xml =  simplexml_load_file('save.xml') or die("can not find file");
$result = $xml->xpath("//property[property_reference='$reference']");
foreach ( $result as $elements){
<img class="card-img-top" height='240px' width='340px' src=" <?php echo 
$elements->pictures->picture[0]->filename  ; ?> " alt="Card image cap"    > 
} ;  
<br>
<?php foreach( $elements as $image) { ?>
<img class="card-img-top" height='240px' width='340px' src=" <?php echo 
$elements->pictures->picture[All of the images]->filename ; ?> " alt="Card image cap"> }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to loop deeper in your structure as you have an array of an array of an array.

**Solution 1: loop deeper**

```
<?php

$reference  = $_POST['varname'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file('save.xml') or die("can not find file");
$result = $xml->xpath("//property[property_reference='$reference']");
foreach ($result as $elements) {
    foreach ($elements as $pictures) {
        foreach ($pictures as $picture) { ?>
            <img class="card-img-top" height='240px' width='340px' src="<?php echo $picture->filename?> " alt="Card image cap"> 
        <?php }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: use a deeper XPath:**

```
<?php

$reference  = $_POST['varname'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file('save.xml') or die("can not find file");
$pictures = $xml->xpath("//property[property_reference='$reference']/pictures");
foreach ($pictures as $picture) { ?>
    <img class="card-img-top" height='240px' width='340px' src="<?php echo $picture->filename?> " alt="Card image cap">
<?php }
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. I managed to get solution 2 working with /pictures/picture  ( so went a  bit deeper again.   Not sure why i had n luck with solution 1.       Do you know of any better resources ?  the php site is next to useless i find. So annoying as your solution shows i was close but i could'nt find the 'simple' resources anywhere